# i18next how to use the Trans component in React Native

Tags: react-native, i18next, react-i18next, react-native-stylesheet, text-styling

How to apply a **bold** weight to certain parts of the translation using the `Trans` component in React Native?

Since HTML tags like `<strong></strong>` don't work, we have to create our own custom `<Strong/>` component that applies certain text styling to the translation, but I don't know how to do that despite reading the [docs](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component)?

Answer (score -2):

Docs:

```js
import { Trans } from 'react-i18next';

function MyComponent({ person, messages }) {
  const { name } = person;
  const count = messages.length;

  return (
    <Trans i18nKey="userMessagesUnread" count={count}>
      Hello <strong title={t('nameTitle')}>{{name}}</strong>, you have {{count}} unread message. <Link to="/msgs">Go to messages</Link>.
    </Trans>
  );
}
```

i guess you can use `<Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{{name}}</Text>` instead of `<strong title={t('nameTitle')}>{{name}}</strong>`.

or using `useTranslation`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

export function MyComponent() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  // or const [t, i18n] = useTranslation();

  return <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{t('my translated text')}</Text>
}
```

*don't test yet*